# Order of operations c#

Tags: c#, operator-precedence

I'm struggling with understanding why the following returns this value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int ans = 10, v1 = 5, v2 = 7, v3 = 18;
ans += v1 + 10 * (v2-- / 5) + v3 / v2;
Console.WriteLine(ans);// prints 28
```

My thinking would be brackets first, division, multiplication then addition.  So the steps would be:
v1 + 10 * (v2-- / 5) + v3 / v2

1. (v2-- / 5)= 1.4, v2 is then set to 6.
2. v3 / v2 = 3
3. 10 * (v2-- / 5) = 14
4. 5 + (14) +(3) = 12

Therefore, (ans += 12) = 22?

Comment: I have seen this, but I'm not sure where i'm going wrong. Isn't my logic correct in terms of that table? : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

Comment: Your first assumption is incorrect.  `?(v2-- / 5)` = 1 not 1.4, because it will produce an integer result

Comment: So you are effectively left with `10 += 5 + 10 * 1 + 3` = `10 += 5 + 10 + 3` = 28

Comment: Thanks Martin. Should have debbuged... X_X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v2-- / 5)= 1.4` and there is your problem. Integer division will *never* return a non integer value.

`1/2` equals `0`, not `0.5` and `7/5` equals `1`, not `1.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Martin: Step 1. is incorrect because both variables are integers the result will be an integer, (v2-- / 5) = 1. To get the answer of 1.4 one would need to change the variables to type double.
"So you are effectively left with 10 += 5 + 10 * 1 + 3= 28"